# Reading csv files in the order in which they appear on my drive

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a folder with almost 7000 csv files named `Edgelist_subgraphXXX.csv`, where the `XXX` stands for a number, from 0 to the last file, for example:

```
Edgelist_subgraph0.csv
Edgelist_subgraph1.csv
Edgelist_subgraph124.csv
Edgelist_subgraph1156.csv
Edgelist_subgraph843.csv
```

I need to read these files **in the correct order** and append the matrices inside the csv to a list. I am doing:

```
path = r'Edgelist_subgraphs' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
all_files.sort()

list_of_edgeList_matrices = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    list_of_edgeList_matrices += [df]
```

However I noticed the files are read in the wrong order. If I print the first few elements of `all_files`, I see why:

```
['Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph0.csv',
 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph1.csv',
 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph10.csv',
 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph100.csv',
 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph1000.csv',
 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph1001.csv',
 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph1002.csv',
 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph1003.csv',
 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph1004.csv',
 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph1005.csv']
```

The sort is a complete mess. Is there a quick and dirty way to sort these files correctly, either in python, or to quickly rename them in bash, something like `0001` instead of `1` at the end?

Comment: Suggestion:  first fetch all file names into a list, then put it into a data frame, add extra columns with regex, order it. then you can fetch data by that order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `key` function to `sort()` in order to sort by numeric value, not alphabetically.

change `all_files.sort()` to `all_files.sort(key=lambda x:int(x[17:-4])`
17 is the len of `Edgelist_subgraph` and -4 is in order to exclude the file extension.
example

```
spam = ['Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph6307.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph2144.csv',
        'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3396.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph6475.csv',
        'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3157.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3345.csv', 
        'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph5739.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3957.csv', 
        'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3938.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph2349.csv'] 

spam.sort(key=lambda x:int(x[36:-4]))
print(spam)
```

output

```
['Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph2144.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph2349.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3157.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3345.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3396.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3938.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3957.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph5739.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph6307.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph6475.csv']
```

or you can use some functions from `os.path`

```
from os.path import basename, splitext
print(basename('Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph6307.csv'))
spam = ['Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph6307.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph2144.csv',
        'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3396.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph6475.csv',
        'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3157.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3345.csv', 
        'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph5739.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3957.csv', 
        'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph3938.csv', 'Edgelist_subgraphs/Edgelist_subgraph2349.csv'] 

spam.sort(key=lambda x:int(basename(x)[17:-4]))
print(spam)
```

Comment: For some reason, your code gives me ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's/Edgelist_subgraph6307'

Comment: it's because of the `s/`.  - you get also the path, not just the file name. You need to exclude the path. My example works with just the file name. If the path is constant you can change 17 to 36 if I calculate path len correctly.

Comment: Oh, it works with : all_files.sort(key=lambda x:int(x[36:-4])), together with the path. Thanks.